# OpenShift unacessible MySQL server

Tags: mysql, redhat, openshift

Aproximetly 4days back, I can access SQL server on OpenShoft Red Hat.

My servlet cant connect to SQL server.
If I try to access server via PHPAdmin a get this error.

## 2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.13.18.130' (111)

On OpenShift Application web page, I can see my Gear with Tomcat6, MySQL 5.1 and phpMyAdmin4.0. No error status or something similar.

I use free plan for 5 months.

Edit1:
I found log from MySQL, where was shutdown.
On this link I found advice, how to restart MySQL server on OpenShift (used rhc).
[OpenShift MySQL server restart](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/mysql-is-not-startedhow-to-fix-cartridge-or-relaunch-it-from-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

If your mysql was shut down, you may want to check your disk space and/or memory usage and make sure that you are not going over quota.  Java applications can eat up memory/disk space quickly, especially on the free tier.